# Best Practice to store KEY-VALUE pairs in JAVA

Tags: java, android

I want to store following data for comparison in Code

> **Cardinal Direction**       **Degree Direction**
>
> ```
> N                348.75 - 11.25
> NNE              11.25 - 33.75
> NE               33.75 - 56.25
> ENE              56.25 - 78.75
> E                78.75 - 101.25
> ESE              101.25 - 123.75
> SE               123.75 - 146.25
> SSE              146.25 - 168.75
> S                168.75 - 191.25
> SSW              191.25 - 213.75
> SW               213.75 - 236.25
> WSW              236.25 - 258.75
> W                258.75 - 281.25
> WNW              281.25 - 303.75
> NW               303.75 - 326.25
> NNW              326.25 - 348.75
> ```

OR

```
500   chance_of_rain
600   chance_of_snow
960   chance_of_storm
801   cloudy
615   flurries
741   fog
721   haze
611   icy
701   mist
804   mostly_cloudy
800   mostly_sunny
803   partly_cloudy
500   rain
711   smoke
601    snow   
960   storm
800   sunny
200   thunderstorm
```

What is the **best way** to store such **2-D Array** data information in android ? either as **res**  or **src**

**NOTES: -**

- Don't want to create database.
- Creating getters setters for these properties and then Making list of this POJO is what   I am aware of and I follow the same.
- Hash MAP I know.

I am just curious whats the best way to store such constant data?

Comment: lol, an array enough ...`new String[] {"NNE", "NE", ... "N"}[Math.floor(((x + 348,75) % 360.0) / 22.5))]`

Comment: @Selvin Maths based answers are the smartest one(haven't even thought some thing such I will witness as answers) but they will remain confined to this particular problem. I was looking for best approach to store such info and iterate thru it without compromising performance even if it grows to larger size then what it actually looks right now

Comment: @Selvin - Math base solution works but in some circumstance which has mathematically achieved result. But if you have a random range for then its not going to work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exact but you can use something like,

[NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) from Java 6. Which has `ceilingEntry()` and `floorEntry()` functions.

Comment: Another one, as a row implementation you can create a Custom Class which has Max and Min Degree Direction which returns a Cardinal Direction for given degree (Make a Method for this).

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final String[] DIRECTIONS = {
    "N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
    "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"
};

String degreeToName(double degree) {
    int corner = (int)((degree + 11.25) / 22.5) % 16; // Or % DIRECTIONS.length
    return DIRECTIONS[corner];
}

String degreeToRange(double degree) {
    int corner = (int)((degree + 11.25) / 22.5) % 16; // Or % DIRECTIONS.length
    double lowerBound = corner * 22.5 - 11.25 + (corner == 0 ? 360 : 0);
    double upperBound = corner * 22.5 + 11.25;
    return String.format("%.2f - %.2f", lowerBound, upperBound);
}
```

A calculation seems best suited.

Under circumstances harden the code with:

```
while (degree < 0) degree += 360;
```

For completeness sake added `degreeToRange`.

Comment: at least one answer with math usage :)